# A question about the Resolution notation in logic

Tags: logic

I currently learning the zero and first order logic,

my textbook defined resolution notation as the following:

---

Let F be a set of clauses. Then Res(F) is defined as

$$Res(F) = F \cup \{R : R~is~a~resolvent~of~two~clauses~in~F\}.$$

Furthermore, we define

$$Res^0(F) = F$$

$$Res^{n+1}(F) = Res(Res^n(F))~for~n ≥ 0,$$

and write

$$Res^∗(F) = \bigcup_{n≥0} Res^{n}(F).$$

---

I thought the above definition implies $Res^0(F)\subseteq Res^1(F)\dots\subseteq Res^{n-1}(F)\subseteq Res^n(F)$

Since $F\subseteq F \cup \{R\}=Res(F)$

Doesn't it mean that $Res^n(F)=Res^*(F)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means $\def\Res{\operatorname{Res}}\Res^n(F)\subseteq\Res^\star(F)$.

Being equal requires that the $n$ resolutions leave no possible pairs of resolvable clauses that have not already been resolved in those $n$ steps.

Because the resolutions of any pair of clauses in $\Res^\star(F)$ will itself be a clause in $\Res^\star(F)$ : ie: there is nothing new to resolve.